# Apagar pasta e conteúdos com o php

Tags: php

Bom galera quero apagar uma pasta do meu site com php, e quero eliminar todos os arquivos e sub-pastas.

Estou usando o seguinte comando:

```
unlink("Arquivos/$token");
```

Isso esta correto? Ele apaga todos os arquivos e sub-pastas?

Esta dando o seguinte erro:

```
Warning: unlink(Arquivos/5b6a7a075e26664fd69e23f60c5d55bc): Operation not permitted in /Library/WebServer/Documents/Sites/Sistema/Paginas/Servidor/Todos_Clientes.php on line 90
```

Comment: Não, o `unlink` apaga somente um arquivo, para apagar o diretório use o `rmdir`.

Comment: Para excluir uma pasta  é `rmdir()`, no entanto, a pasta deve estar vazia. Para resolver precisa criar uma recursividade e checando o que for arquivo use `unlink()`, o que for pasta, use `rmdir()`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Você pode usar essa função PHP que apaga a pasta e seus arquivos internos:

```
    function delTree($dir) { 
      $files = array_diff(scandir($dir), array('.','..')); 
      foreach ($files as $file) { 
        (is_dir("$dir/$file")) ? delTree("$dir/$file") : unlink("$dir/$file"); 
      } 
      return rmdir($dir); 
    }

    delTree('caminho/da/pasta/aqui');
```

Essa função esta no próprio [manual do php](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.rmdir.php#110489)

Espero ter ajudado.

Comment: e como eu tenho o retorno true ou false dessa função?

Comment: true ou false?...  seria para confirmar se realmente excluiu?

Comment: basta atribuir a função para uma variável de controle. **$ok = delTree('minha/pasta');** . Você pode usar em conjunto a função **is_dir** para verificar se realmente existe aquele arquivo/pasta que você quer apagar.

Comment: Muito bom, funcionou 100%, obrigado